# Stab a 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d array from which I am trying to a list of stabs. Put another way, given the array:

```
t = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]])

array([[[ 1,  2],
      [ 3,  4]],

     [[ 5,  6],
      [ 7,  8]],

     [[ 9, 10],
      [11, 12]]])
```

I am trying to retrieve:

```
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

`np.ndarray.reshape` seems to reorganise elements in a sequential order that precludes stabs.

`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` might work, but I have yet to find the correct combination of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpose then reshape:

```
>>> t.transpose(1, 2, 0).reshape(4, 3)
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

Edit: alternatively, you can reshape then transpose:

```
>>> t.reshape(3, 4).T
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```